# Marshaling akka-http

Tags: scala, marshalling, akka-http, spray-json

```
class Converter extends 
RootJsonFormat[TypeToConvert]
{
def write(obj : TypeToConvert) : JsValue =
{
    obj match
    {
        case Https => JsString(Https.name)
        case Sms => JsString(Sms.name)
    }
}   
def read(jsValue : JsValue) : TypeToConvert =
{
    jsValue match
    {
        case JsString("HTTPS") => Https
        case JsString("SMS") => Sms
        case _ => throw 
  DeserializationException("Expected a TypeToConvert
    Type")
     }
  }
}
```

I have written a converter like this and in this I am using only write method. Is there a way to write json formatters with only write method. I want to remove read method.

Comment: i don't think it is possible to do so you will have to write both read, as well as write methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
trait RootJsonFormat[T] extends JsonFormat[T] with RootJsonReader[T] with RootJsonWriter[T]
```

As you can see this is how the hirearchy is of RootJsonFormat which extends JsonFormat. Which is using RootJsonReader as well as RootJsonWriter. If you want to use only the JsonWriter. Then extend your class with RootJsonWriter.

You are using RootJsonFormat with your class in that case you will have to use define write and read methods.

```
class Converter extends 
RootJsonWriter[TypeToConvert]
{
def write(obj : TypeToConvert) : JsValue =
{
    obj match
    {
        case Https => JsString(Https.name)
        case Sms => JsString(Sms.name)
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Is there a predefined method in spray json that provides only writer implementation for a case class? 
Like jsonFormat5(...) provides the implementation for both read and write ?

Comment: you can create custom Json formatter, i don't think there is some inbuilt formatter with only write implementation because it doesn't make sense to have only write implementation.

Comment: Actually, at this point, I am doing only marshaling using the write method only and I don't want any unused code in my project.

Comment: This is not how it works!! i mean it's not unused code if you will not have the reader then how you gonna unmarshall your request? from json to caseClass? this way you can only do the other way that is marshaling from caseClass to json. You need to have both.

Comment: why can't you do as i answered? use RoojJsonWriter it should work

Comment: Actually, this type that i want to convert is used in another class and i have defined a jsonFormatter13(...) for that another class, which requires both read and write methods.
So this RootJsonWriter[..] doesn't work with that class.

Comment: When you know you need both reader and writer when why you are saying that you are only using writer?